# Puzzle: Players $A,B,C,D$ are in a line

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recreational-mathematics, intuition, puzzle, game-theory

[image]

Players $A,B,C,D$ stands in a line.

Players $A, D$ do not move.

round $1:$ player $B$ moves one distance closer to the midpoint of $A$ and $C$

round $2:$ player $C$ moves one distance closer to the midpoint of $B$ and $D$

How should I formulate the problem so to prove that $A,B,C,D$ will be at equidistant at the end of this game?

Comment: It isn't clear how to formally express moving "one distance closer" to a midpoint.  Are distances and movements in discrete units?  If exactly at a midpoint is there no movement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question might need some refinement to avoid oscillations around the convergence of $B$ to $\frac{1}{3}$ of $AD$ and $C$ to $\frac{2}{3}$ of $AD$. So it is clear that you don't want to have movements on grid and you may avoid the term "one distance". Why not just stating that $B$ moves to the midpoint of $AC$ and $C$ moves to the midpoint of $BD$?
Assume $A$ at $0$ and $D$ at $1$.

By observing that a move of $B$ is limited into the range of $0-0.5$ while $C$ may be at any point on $AD$, and $C$ moves to the segment $0.5-1$ when $B$ is anywhere on $AD$ you may realize that the dependency between $B$ and $C$ moves could lead to convergence.
When $B$ and $C$ are limited to the $0-0.5$ and $0.5-1$ ranges you could show that this derives that actually they will be limited to $0.25-0.5$ for $B$ and $0.5-0.75$ for $C$.

Since you are not asking for a solution I will leave it here and hope to be granted the solution:)

The following table demonstrate the ranges convergence for the $B$ and $C$ values:

$$\begin{array}{| 1 | 1| 1| 1| 1| 1| 1| 1| 1| 1| 1|}
\hline
B_{min} & 0 & 0.00  &  0.25 & 0.25 & 0.31 & 0.31 & 0.33 & 0.33 & 0.33 & 0.33 \\ \hline
B_{max} & 1 & 0.50 & 0.50 & 0.38 & 0.38 & 0.34 & 0.34 & 0.34 & 0.34 & 0.33 \\ \hline
C_{min} & 0 & 0.50 & 0.50 & 0.63 & 0.63 & 0.66 & 0.66 & 0.66 & 0.66 & 0.67 \\ \hline
C_{max} & 1 & 1.00 & 0.75 & 0.75 & 0.69 & 0.69 & 0.67 & 0.67 & 0.67 & 0.67 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$